# How to get config data in laravel in a subfolder

Tags: php, laravel

I have the [Laravel Administrator Plugin](https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator) and I set up a setting administrator page that is located in:

app/config/administrator/settings/site.php

The application can store the data, but when i try to get some data in one of my controllers like this:

Config::get('administrator.settings.site')

I can get a returned value... Always null or array 0.

How I can get those configuration values?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Solution:

You can use a file path rather than dot notation for file paths:

```
Config::get('administrator/settings/site.variable_name');
```

### Some Explanation

Dot notation is used to get variables inside the config array within a file, rather than to denote file paths.

Therefore you can use `Config::get('administrator/settings/site.variable_name');` to get $variable_name from `administrator/settings/site.php`, or `ENV_DIR_NAME/administrator/settings/site.php` depending on your environment.

Directories within in `app/config` are read as environments. For example `app/development/database.php` will work with `Config::get('database.whatever')` when you're in your "development" environment while `app/production/database.php` will be read with `Config::get('database.whatever')` when you're in the "production" environment.

Laravel falls back to the `config/config/*.php` file when no environment-specific file is present.

### Note

I believe that admin package has a [config file](http://administrator.frozennode.com/docs/configuration) in `app/config/packages/frozennode/administrator/administrator.php` which the package would like you to use for it's settings. That should be available using [this convention](http://laravel.com/docs/packages#package-configuration): `Config::get('package::file.option');`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar problem when using this [Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) package.

The solution I needed was slightly different to the solution above. I needed to take advantage of Laravel's config overriding feature to have one config setting for normal execution and a different one for testing. Specifically, I normally wanted Excel files to be stored in `storage/excel` and I wanted them to be put in `storage/testing/excel` under testing.

The technique of using a slashed path didn't work because it points to a specific file so didn't respect the different environments:

```
$directory = Config::get('packages/maatwebsite/excel/export.store.path');
```

The solution was to use a package prefix so that the config loader would respect the environment:

```
$directory = Config::get('excel::export.store.path');
```

I'm not exactly sure where the `excel` shorthand name comes from but I suspect it's something to do with [the Excel facade](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/master/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/Facades/Excel.php) in the package exposing itself as `'excel'`.