# Laravel Config::get() from particular environment (not current)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to get a config value from another (not current) environment. I would like to get it calling something like:

```
$value = Config::get('app.locale', 'default', 'my_environment');
```

Obviuosly Config::get() takes only 2 params by default, but are there any other functions to get config in neat way, to get what I want? I can't find anything in the API.

Comment: No, that's what environments are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer to this question [How to get config data in laravel in a subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532449/how-to-get-config-data-in-laravel-in-a-subfolder) happens to be a solution for me as well.

Rather than passing some other parameters to Config::get(), you can pass a path to file in the first parameter. So calls like:

```
Config::get('local/app.locale');
Config::get('dev/app.locale');
```

will get config from local, dev, etc. environments, no matter what's your current working environment.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel environments, are for seperating configurations from develop machine and production machine.

If you want on all env. the same config you can use the global config files in `app/config/*` for individual configuration per env. you use the `app/config/<YOUR ENVIRONMENT>`.

so to get your `app.locale` in all environment the same use the `app/config/app.php` file

Comment: I'm aware of how environments work. My intention of using such a config::get() is deliberate and not inconsistent with the whole environment concept. I found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532449/how-to-get-config-data-in-laravel-in-a-subfolder

Comment: You are misusing environments.