# Laravel File with return Array

Tags: laravel, return

In laravel there are files like app.php or auth.php which contains one array with specific settings. For my application i want to create a file that contains all my query's like the same way in one array and return it. How could i use the file for example app.php in my controller

## Example

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Query 1
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is an example of a query 
    |
    */

        'sql_user_by_name' => "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = 'test'",
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place it in the config directory you can use this:

```
Config::get('myfile.myproperty');
```

So in you're case:

```
Config::get('app.sql_user_by_name');
```

You can also use the build in function of Laravel. This works the same:

```
config('app.sql_user_by_name');
```

You can look at the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1). Please scroll down to "Accessing Configuration Values".

Comment: Thx, and if i want to use it in another directory?? And where can i find how laravel reads thouse files, so i could learn about it.

Comment: You've to look at the [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php).

Comment: For information about different folders [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532449/how-to-get-config-data-in-laravel-in-a-subfolder) will help you I guess.

Comment: Thx for all the information this was exactly what i need. But for my learning curve i would like to know how laraval reads the file. Is it includes somewhere??

Comment: It's always good to read the source. Do it yourself https://github.com/laravel/framework :)

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a1dc78820d2dbf207dbdf0f7075f17f7021c4ee8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php . Here Laravel is loading the configuration.

Comment: And here you see the configuration path: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a1dc78820d2dbf207dbdf0f7075f17f7021c4ee8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L310 Thanks for accepting

Comment: Thank you for your fast response